# GPKG and GPKG-WAL - not sure if main process finished

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics, geopackage

I am performing ZonalStatistics (mean value from a Float32 virtual raster) in QGIS 3.4 on a huge geopackage layer. Originally it was 240 GB and after few days the process became odd:

- The QGIS process bar shows that the algorithm is on 100 % while the ZonalStatistics windows show 99 % already 4 days
- The GPKG-WAL file is being still updated all the time and now it came to the size of 220 GB - and it is increasing (the GPKG is 278 GB)

What is happening really? Is the main process over or not? How big can this GPKG-WAL become (based on the main GPKG size) and should I wait for the process to finish or stop it?
[image: geopackage files]

[image]

Comment: I copied and checked just the GPKG file and it was half empty, which maybe implies, that the gpkg-wal file had the other part of the results (and was still calculating) and did not yet update the gpkg.

Comment: Did the process finally complete?  What was the final result?

Comment: @StuSmith The process dis not complete in 5 days. I was at that point in a hurry and I've decided to append a bunch of SHP to a PostGIS table and ditched the idea od doing it with Geopackage again. I am still interested in the reasons and have searched for the answers allover the SQLite sources and forums, but couldn't conclude anything.